# How to disable authorization in Django for registration?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using to authentication this:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as rest_auth_views

url(r'^login/', rest_auth_views.obtain_auth_token)
```

Everything works fine but in order to create new account I have to send token in header what is wrong. I'm creating new account using such view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def UserList(request):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can I disable authentication for user registration? Maybe my method or line of thought is wrong?
**SOLUTION:**

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method =='POST' or (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser):
            return True
        return False

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([CustomPermission])
def UserList(request):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Can you show your entire view from the very start? i.e. from the `def` line

Comment: @AndreTerra I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import `AllowAny` permission and add the class to the view,

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.decorators import permisson_classes

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def UserList(request):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Or using the class based views,

```
from rest_framwork.views import APIView

class UserListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As @Andre Terra had mentioned the above method could compromise some behaviours, because of the fact that any one could retrieve the list of users using a GET request.

For overcoming the same, I'd recommend writing a custom permission for the view. It would be something like this,

```
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method =='POST' or (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser): 
            return True 
        return False
```

Now, only a superusers can get the list of users.

Comment: Appreciate the support, brother!!

Comment: @Wahtdbogh These will allow a non-authenticated user to list every user with GET, which may go beyond your original intent of letting such user create their account. I'd personally separate UserList from UserCreate as these refer to different things (every user vs. one user)

Comment: In the near future I'm going to add permissions so for instance only admin will be able to list every user with GET. But maybe even then it would be better to separate these two things? The answer seems to be YES, because in my opinion admin should have access to list all users, however every user should have possibility to create account without admin permissions.

Comment: You should separate views when they refer to different resources or actions, not when permissions differ because permissions can always be defined per-method rather than per-view. At least that's my take on it. Having said that, @FazilZaid's solution works perfectly so maybe just go with that for now

Comment: I totally agree with you@Andre Terra.

Comment: I have added my solution, is it ok?

Comment: you could define all the permissions in a separate file `permissions.py`, then import them in `views.py` like, `from .permissions import CustomPermission`...That'd be more readable don't you think?